# Bug on tab change in Chrome 32

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, render

I'm having some strange bug on Chrome v32.

When user loads my website (http://www.superplayer.fm), it is rendered correctly, but when the user change tab and came back to my site, it became small, on the left bottom corner of the screen.

This occurs on Chrome 32, Chrome beta, and Chrome Canary.

I've tried to remove any css transitions of my code, and tried to remove listeners to resize, scroll and other js events. Nothing worked. Also, when the dev console is opened, this bug don't happen.

This started to happen on version 32, before was working perfectly.

Do you know something about this?

[image: Here a screen shot]

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Works for me (Chrome 32). Did you try to disable all extensions?

Comment: Works for me too (on Win7 64bit) BTW, I've became interested in your website :)

Comment: @Andy, yes tried that too, thanks

Comment: @HashemQolami, Thanks! This errors seems to be happening only in the windows 8

Answer (score 2):

removing this css solved the issue for me:

```
webkit-filter: blur(0) grayscale(0%);
```

[image: root cause, maybe?]